# Port mapping between container port and hosted application(inside container) port

Tags: docker-compose

I am creating a container using docker compose. which has an application expecting requests at port :5000.
But i want to expose port 80 from the container.
So is there any way where i can map all the incoming request at 80 to 5000 in container.
This works in Kube yaml by setting target port to 5000 and exposing 80 but not sure how to do it in docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

It would look like this in the docker-compose file.

```
ports:
    -"80:5000"
```

Comment: This will try to map container’s 5000 port to docker host’ port 80. What i want is expose port 80 of container but request should be sent to 5000 on running application inside the container